# how to do I preserve guid fields from access to sql server?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a table in Access 2007 with a field w/ data type = Number. In access, that field stores guids w/numbers and letters in them. When I right click the table and choose export, then I export it to SQL server -- the table shows up in SQL server w/guids w/ only numbers in them.

How can I preserve the GUIDs between Access and SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing simple export to SQL, run SQL Server Upsize wizard from Database Tools menu:

[image: SQL Server upsize wizard]

This way Replication ID values will be preserved as GUIDs in SQL Server tables.